# How to set conditional output under while loop?

Tags: python, error-handling, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am working on a tiny project that create a guessing game.
It will let the user to put in their guess, and the code will compared input with the random number. If the input is smaller, the code will say 'Higher' and let the user enter again. If the input is smaller, the code will say 'Lower' and let the user input again. If the two are the same, the loop will break, and return how many times the user spent guessing.

Here are the code I've done. It will stop running after the user give 2 answers. Could you point out where the error is?

```
def guessing_game():
    print('Guess a number between 1 and 100')
    user = int(input(''))
    from random import randint
    secret_answer = randint(1, 100)
    x = 0
    while user > secret_answer or user >= secret_answer:
        x += 1
        if user > secret_answer:
            print('Lower!')
            user = int(input(''))
        elif user < secret_answer:
            print('Higher!')
            user = int(input(''))
        else:
            print('Impressive! You got the correct answer in ' + str(x) + ' guesses!')
            break
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `user > secret_answer or user >= secret_answer` condition means that if the user ever makes a guess lower than `secret_answer`, the loop will stop. It would make more sense to instead change it to `while True`, so that the program is in control of when the loop breaks, and not the user.

```
while True:
    x += 1
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thank you for pointing out! It should be > and <= instead...

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is incorrect. You can simplify the entire process thus:

```
from random import randint

def guessing_game():
    user = int(input('Guess a number between 1 and 100: '))
    secret_answer = randint(1, 100)
    x = 1
    while user != secret_answer:
        prompt = 'Higher: ' if user < secret_answer else 'Lower: '
        user = int(input(prompt))
        x += 1
    print(f'Impressive! You got the correct answer in {x} guesses!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    guessing_game()
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I see you used prompt syntax in the loop; what is the prompt's function?

Comment: *prompt* is a merely a variable that I assign separately just to make the code clearer. There is no "prompt syntax"

Comment: Thanks for your explanation; I understand that part now. What is the if __name__ part doing here? It seems calling out the function here.

Comment: @ArcKong You could actually remove the conditional test in this case. It's something I do out of habit. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!! And an additional piece of question here if it's not too much for you, what is conditional test doing?